# Does DCl have a higher rotational partition function (qrot) than HCl? And if so why?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry

I know that DCl has a higher moment of inertia than HCl, but I can't really explain how this actually affects the rotational partition function, I know larger molecules have a higher moment of inertia and this means the energy levels are closer, but I don't know how to explain how this has an effect on the partition function of rotation, can someone help?

Comment: Do you know how to obtain an expression for the rotational partition function (specifically, by approximating the sum as an integral and evaluating the subsequent integral)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partition function is the sum over states, which means over all the energy levels, thus
$$Z=\sum _i g_i \exp(-E_i/(k_BT))$$ 
where $g_i$ is the degeneracy of each level with energy $E_i$. The rigid rotor rotational energy levels of a diatomic molecules are $$E_J= \hbar^2J(J+1)/(2I)$$ where *I* is the moment of inertia $I=\mu r^2$ for reduced mass $\mu=m_1m_2/(m_1+m_2)u $ (in kg) and bond length *r*. The degeneracy of rotational levels is $g_J=2J+1$.

As the moment of inertial of DCl is greater than that of HCl (due to reduced mass effect) the energy levels are lower in energy in DCl at the same *J* than in HCl and so at the *same temperature* more levels are populated and the partition function is greater. This means that the exponential term in the partition function is greater in DCl at a given *J* and so this increases the partition function. (recall that $e^0 = 1$ and $e^{-\text{big number}} \rightarrow 0$). The energy levels of DCl and HCl are shown in the left figure and the terms in the partition function on the right as $g_J \exp(-E_J/(k_BT))$. (The curves are plotted for clarity assuming that *J* is  continuous not discrete). The respective partition function is the sum of the values at each *J* in the right-hand figure.

[image: partition function]

(To plot the curves I used a mass of Cl = $35$ and H and D, $1$ & $2$ respectively. The unified atomic mass unit $u = 1.660\cdot 10^{-27}$ kg, and assume a temperature of $300$ K. The bond length is $74.15$ pm.)

(Note that the often used integral form of the partition function has a systematic error that does not imporove as *J* increases.)